# WPF Prism C# observe DB change and update

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

I have a dashboard which when the constructor is called fetches data from DB and updates `listbox` accordingly. Once I navigate to new tab to add element to DB and navigate back to dashboard, the view is not updated. I have `ObservableCollection` defined, and it functions well if I for example delete the element from the list inside the dashboard view.

Since I use `Prism`, I  have implemented `INavigationAware` on dashboard, and when done in that way, the update works both ways (deletion and adding new), but the problem is that the other property I need consistent just doesn't stay that way since the whole `ViewModel` class gets instantiated once again when I navigate back to the view.

Here is the constructor:

```
public DashboardViewModel()
{
    service = new Service.ServiceManager();
    controller = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceName == service.ServiceName);
    lbPlugins = new ObservableCollection<Plugin>();
    lbPlugins.AddRange(new DbRepository().GetContext().PluginSet);
    StartStopInit();
}
```

It is possible to install a win service through the program, and dashboard checks if the service is in start or stop mode:

```
private void StartStopService()
{
    if (startStopTxt == "Start")
    {
        service.StartService();
    }
    else
    {
        service.StopService();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I implement `INavigationAware` the service gets somehow overwritten. I was checking if it is fetching the right name, and it is...but it looks like it generates a new instance, and now I am able to start the service again...which shouldn't be possible...

Comment: Do you really require `INavigationAware` to be implemented? If you use it that way, then obviously the ViewModel will be re instantiated. I would recommend starting the service in some other function rather than the constructor. Maybe inside the parent class or during load event.

Comment: Well I'm trying to avoid it, but didn't yet find a way to do it. I was thinking of making some element observe db context property or something...to update when db is changed...but don't know if its possible

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any reason for `new`ing the service manager. Register it with unity as a singleton and have it injected as dependency:

```
// in the bootstrapper / module initialization
Container.RegisterType<ServiceManager>( new ContainerControllerLifetimeManager() );

// in the view model's constructor
public DashboardViewModel( ServiceManager serviceManager )
{
    serviceManager.StartOrStopTheService();
}
```

Comment: Agree with @Haukinger, best way to handle shared state that more than one view depends on is hold it in a service and inject the service into the ViewModels. Otherwise it is up to your code to persist and load consistently with OnNavigatingTo and OnNavigatingFrom. What often trips people up here is not realizing that if your View is being navigated to in a region, the Prism RegionManager is holding a reference to it, so you won't get a Loaded event in the view or a fresh construction of the ViewModel when you nav away and nav back - that is what the INavigationAware methods are for.